# Sockets in C, Non-blocking send() and recv() with select() method

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip

I want to make a non-blocking send() and recv() with select() and FD_ISSET(). I run into this behavior in which FD_ISSET() will be true for the first socket, and all other sockets are always not ready. I am confused why that is happening and I am wondering if I am using select() properly.

If I sent 100 requests, eventually one of the socket other than the first will be ready to recv(), but I am not getting that behavior.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < P - 1; i++) {
    sockArr[i] = GetSocket(server, port);
    if (sockArr[i] < 0) {
      // handle error
    }
    fcntl(sockArr[i], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if(sockArr[i] > maxfd) {
      maxfd = sockArr[i];
    }
  }

  fd_set sockSet;
  for(int i = 0; i < P - 1; i++) {
    numBytes = send(sockArr[i], request, requestLen, 0);
    if (numBytes < 0 || numBytes != requestLen) {
      // handle error
    }

    // read from other stackoverflow post you need to rest
    // per select() call
    FD_ZERO(&sockSet);
    for(int i = 0; i < P - 1; i++) {
      FD_SET(sockArr[i], &sockSet);
    }

    if(select(maxfd+1, &sockSet, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(FD_ISSET(sockArr[j], &sockSet)) { // <------ only true for j = 0
         numBytes = recv(sockArr[j], buffer, MAXBUFLEN - 1, 0);
          if (numBytes < 0) {
            // handle error
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have the `select` inside a `for` loop? That seems weird. Are you really intending to do one `send` followed by a `select`, and then two `send` followed by a `select`, and so on? Or did you mean to do all the `send` calls followed by a single `select`?

Comment: Basically I need to sent P amount of requests to a server in parallel and record the request time of the tail latency (90% completion time vs 100% completion time). There are more logic inside the for-loop to keep track of the amount recv()'ed

Comment: Well you are not sending P requests in parallel. You are sending *one* request and then blocking on `select`.

Comment: Maybe I am understanding Beej's network guide incorrectly. I thought the whole point of using `O_NONBLOCK` along with `select()` is so that there wouldn't be any blocking?

Comment: You are not quite understanding the whole picture. `O_NONBLOCK` only affects the actual IO operations `read`, `write`, `send`, `recv`, etc. It doesn't affect `select`. It wouldn't make sense if it did. What is the point of `select` if it doesn't block? In that case you may as well just immediately call `recv` and check its return value to see if any data was read.

Comment: What is your recommendation that I should do such that I sent out N request and `recv()` immediately if any of the N sockets are available to be received? Should I just do what you've said. Call `recv()` and see if any data was read?

Comment: No. Your code is almost there. Just need to take out the select/recv block to be outside the `for` loop. Then you have a single `select` call inside either an infinete loop or a loop that exits on an appropriate condition. After the `select` call you have exactly the `recv` code that you have now (including its enclosing for loop).

Comment: Wouldn't `sent()` time affects the timing of latency? If the sent to server time is long and receive from server time is long but shorter than `sent()`. Then `sent()` effectively buffered for the wait time for recv()?

Comment: Wait, nvm. I am using non-blocking sent(). Thanks! @kaylum

Answer (score 0):

Your first `for` loop needs to terminate after the `send()` calls, and you should then start another to handle the selects and receives.

You need to check for `recv()` returning zero as well as -1, and close the socket and remove it from the FD set in either case.

You also need to loop while `j <= P`.

Comment: I needed to record time of the P-th completed request. That is why I have `select()` and `recv()` inside the for-loop. I have another while loop to get the remaining P requests. Not too sure if how badly `sent()` will effect the recording time.  I used `j < i` because `i` is the amount of request I have sent, do I won't need to check the rest right?